# Select rows from sales table when sale date is > than the lowest order_date in order table for each ProductID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I Have 2 tables, one for Product sales and another for Product orders from suppliers.

Sales table contains : (ProductID, Sale date, customer ID, etc)

Orders table contains (ProductID, Order date, Supplier ID etc).

Each product on sales table was sold many times and each product of Orders table was ordered many times. 
For each product ID, I want to query the sales tables to return only rows where the sale dates of that product are higher than the earliest order date for that product. For example, there may be a product that was sold even before the very first time it was ordered from the suppliers, for each productID, I want to eliminate those rows with such dates and only keep those that came after the earliest order from suppliers. Any ideas on how to go about doing that in `SQL`, `MySQL` or `NetezzaSQL`? Thanks !

---

### Sales Table:

*ProductID* | *Sale_date* | *CustomerID*

### Orders Table :

*ProductID* | *Order_Date* | *SupplierID*

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.*, o.*
from sales s
inner join (select product.id,min(order_date) min_order_date, supplier_id from orders) o
on s.product_id = o.product_id and s.sale_date > o.min_order_date
```

If I understood correctly the above should do the trick!

In any case dont hesitate to comment here with more questions :)

Ted

Comment: Thank you ! I want the min date for each productID, When you use "min" does it do the min of date in the whole table or the min for each given productID?